# Best way to design Android App with actionbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar

I want to develop an Android app by using an ActionBar. Currently I'm on the beginning of the app and got an Activity, with ActionBar and some Fragments. I can already change the tabs. But I've got problems with the ActionBar, when moving from Fragment to another Fragment.

I read, thats not the usecase, to use Activity with ActionBar.

But, what is the best practise for this scenario?

MainApplication

- Tab 1:

  - ListView
- Tab 2:

  - ListView -> DetailView
- Tab 3:

  - ListView -> DetailView
- Settings-Button in ActionBar:

  - ListView -> DetailView

Should I create 4 Activities for each Tab or better Fragments?

Comment: Well if you want the title to change based on the tab fragment just change the title if i got you right or else use `ViewPager` i think that will be better

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way is to create a custom action bar and modify it according to the activity. Here is an example..

First you have to create layout for custom action bar in order define functionality according to your requirement. Here is the xml file...

layout for custom action bar :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/custom_actionbar_back_iv"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/small_margin_ar"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/very_small_margin_ar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/up_navigation"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/custom_actionbar_titleText_tv"
    style="@style/wrapscreen"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/custom_actionbar_back_iv"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/above_medium_text_size" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/custom_actionbar_goToArchiveActivity_ib"
    style="@style/wrapscreen"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/medium_margin"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow" />
```

Here goes the implementation..

Define setupactionBar() method in onCreate() method

```
private void setUpActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View customActionBarView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

        // this view is used to show tile
        TextView ActivityTitleTV = (TextView) customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.custom_actionbar_titleText_tv);
        ActivityTitleTV.setText(R.string.title_text_archive);

        //this view can be used for back navigation
        ImageView backToRecorderIV = (ImageView) customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.custom_actionbar_back_iv);
        backToRecorderIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        backToRecorderIV.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Another view which has up navigation
        ImageButton goToArchiveActivityIB = (ImageButton) customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.custom_actionbar_goToArchiveActivity_ib);
        goToArchiveActivityIB.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBarView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }

    //listener for back navigation
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.custom_actionbar_back_iv:
                Intent recorder = new Intent(ArchiveActivity.this, RecorderActivity.class);
                startActivity(recorder);
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps...